# determine necessary current to drive a stepper motor?

Tags: driver, stepper-motor

I am trying to drive a stepper motor. It is a 12V unipolar [motor](http://www.crcibernetica.com/12vdc-28byj-48-unipolar-stepper-motor/). But it is not moving. I tried with L293D , ULN2003 etc. I think it is not getting sufficient current. But how do I determine how much current is necessary, so that I can chose a driver IC? In the [datasheet](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Stepper-Motor-28BJY-48-Datasheet.pdf) there is no current mentioned.

Comment: My question might be naive.. have you driven any other stepper motor earlier?

Comment: Model specification has the phase resistance as 300 Ohms. Current should be 12/300 = 40 mA per phase and zero until phase is changed.. Correct me if i am wrong. If possible, share the wiring diagram

Comment: No,this is my first time with a stepper motor.

Comment: https://learn.adafruit.com/all-about-stepper-motors/what-is-a-stepper-motor Doesn't take much time. Stepper motor is a must in so many robotics and motored drives. Learn more about it. Driving motor is easy.

Answer (score 1):

This type of stepper does not use much current, in the [datasheet](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Stepper-Motor-28BJY-48-Datasheet.pdf), you can see that

Stepper has gear reduction **1:64**

Step angle $${360\text{º}\over64\text{º steps}} = 5.625º\text{ pr step}$$

which is full-step.

Resistance per phase is

$${12\text{V}\over300\text{Ω}} = 40\text{mA}$$

If you need more current than the circuit can provide, then you must use a power driver like this.

[image]

You can find more information [here](https://www.google.dk/search?q=stepper%20motor%20driver&safe=off&biw=1491&bih=858&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=NVWOVdSdI4yXsAGdiaHgDQ&sqi=2&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#safe=off&tbm=isch&q=unipolar%20stepper%20motor%20driver&imgrc=_)

Answer (score 0):

Moving a stepper may be not  as trivial as it seems. Do you hear it trying make steps? Most of the beginners drive it without motion profile, skipping the acceleration, so the motor sometimes doesn't follow and only make noise.

Also the motor is bipolar. Are you sure, you are driving the steps correctly? Reminder: you have four steps:

Phase A: I, phase B: I
Phase A: I, phase B: - I
Phase A: - I, phase B: - I
Phase A: - I, phase B: I

This is the order of currents.

Of course, it is expected that the current is controlled, otherwise when the motor is not moving, it may rise and burn things or dip the power supply.

If you can, start with Drv8818. It's more adequate for your problem.

Comment: The components you use fit unipolar steppers. They indeed are easier to use, but the motor you show is different.

Comment: I don't get it. The motor is supposed to be unipolar. As I know, bipolar motors have 4 wires, where unipolar ones have 5-6 wires. Mine has 5. Also, the website says its unipolar.

Comment: The datasheet shows a bipolar motor, i think. Two inductors... In unipolar motors you have central tap of winding to put +12 there, and then you pull down each of the other four wires in turn.